# Why “Would you mind if I asked you something?” is correct?

Tags: phrases, past-tense

Instead of "Would you mind if I ask you something?" Why past tense, I don't get it?

Comment: A person would mind *after* something has been *asked*. Therefore the past tense. That's how I see it.

Comment: Nope. It is *asked* because it is *would*. Note how it's "will you mind if I ask you something".